# Why the result of conditional / ternary operator may differ from if-else statements in some c++ types?

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

Here is my code:

```
// defs
string untrusted_ip;
const char * get_env (const char *name, const char *envp[]);
string User::getCommonname(void);
void User::setStatusFileKey(string);
void User::setKey(string);

// 1
                if( get_env ( "untrusted_ip", envp ) !=NULL ){
                    newuser->setStatusFileKey(newuser->getCommonname() +string ( "," ) + untrusted_ip + string ( ":" ) + get_env ( "untrusted_port", envp ) );
                    newuser->setKey(untrusted_ip + string ( ":" ) + get_env ( "untrusted_port", envp ) );
                }else{
                    newuser->setStatusFileKey(newuser->getCommonname() +string ( "," ) + untrusted_ip);
                    newuser->setKey(untrusted_ip);
                }
                
// 2
                newuser->setStatusFileKey(newuser->getCommonname() +string ( "," ) + untrusted_ip + get_env ( "untrusted_ip", envp ) != (const char*)NULL ? string ( ":" ) + get_env ( "untrusted_port", envp ) : string("") );
                newuser->setKey(untrusted_ip + get_env ( "untrusted_ip", envp ) != (const char*)NULL ? string ( ":" ) + get_env ( "untrusted_port", envp ) : string("") );
```

modified from https://salsa.debian.org/debian/openvpn-auth-radius/-/blob/master/radiusplugin.cpp#L446

block 1 and 2 seems to be equal but 1 works as expected while 2 does not work (seems not executing, for break point is not triggered).

What is the core difference between the two blocks of codes?

Also, only `get_env ( "untrusted_ip", envp ) != (const char*)NULL` in conditional operator can pass compilation while `if( get_env ( "untrusted_ip", envp ) !=NULL )` is possible. What is the reason and are the two problems connected?

P.S. I am using gcc/g++ 10.2.1

Comment: Read about operator's precedence and look carefully on 2nd version.

Comment: I would add extra parenthesis...

Comment: both are equally unreadable

Comment: the conditional operator is in general not a drop in replacement for an if else. With `T x = E1 ? E2 : E3;` the relation and possible conversions between `E2` and `E3` matter to determine the type of the right hand side of `=`. With `if (E1) x = E2; else x = E3;` relations between `E2` and `E3` are irrelevant. As a result `x` can potentially be something entierly different

Comment: OT: `NULL` is the old C-compatibility macro for null pointers, in C++ use `nullptr`. Also don't call `get_env` multiple times, call it once and store the result to be reused. And since you have common code in both branches (the `getCommoName()` etc.) pull it out to also store in a common variable that can be used and reused.

Comment: As an aside, it is *not* a speed optimization to write hard to read code. The compiler will do the transformation for you, in case there is faster way to do things. "Easy to read" is a sign of high quality code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an [*operator precedence*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) issue.

The additions operator `+` have higher precedence than `!=` so the expression is equivalent to (slightly rewritten to make it easier to see):

```
auto result = newuser->getCommonname() +string ( "," ) + untrusted_ip + get_env ( "untrusted_ip", envp );

newuser->setStatusFileKey(
    result != (const char*)NULL 
    ?
    string ( ":" ) + get_env ( "untrusted_port", envp )
    :
    string("") );
```

This is one of the many cases where the conditional expression makes the code not only harder to read and understand, but also makes it wrong.

The `if else` version is much easier to read and understand, and correct.